# Could not find module 'AWSMobileClient' for target 'arm64-apple-ios'

Tags: mqtt, swift5, aws-sdk-ios

i am getting error , while adding SDK inside my Custom SDK
Could not find module 'AWSMobileClient' for target 'arm64-apple-ios'; found: x86_64-apple-ios-simulator, x86_64

[image]